# Redirect a raw C array data into a data file in embedded system industries

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, binaryfiles

I have seen some codes that have no function. They just have data and the file is supposed to be converted to a data file not an executable.

For example, it is something like

config.c

```
const unsigned char configData[] = \
"Cnf"
"\0x01\0x01\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00"
"LOCAL/ITEM.MSG\0x00"
"\x7E\xD1\xF5\x3A\0x00\0x00\0x00";
```

The file is supposed to turn into `config.dat` as binary starting with `Cnf\0x01\0x01...` and ending with `\xF5\x3A\0x00\0x00\0x00` with no header or footer.

What is the name of such an action? I have problem for google keywords.

And, how can such an action be done using a `gcc` compiler?

---

**Update**: I am not after using `fwrite` or a library. I do not want to add anything to the above code or remove any line from it. Lets keep this file intact. My problem is not to create a binary file. My problem is mostly understanding how these particular files are handled by the compiler. I have seen such files in the embedded system industries. But not yet found how they work.

Comment: C source files certainly aren't obligated to contain any function definitions, but there is no standard mechanism for a direct file conversion such as you seem to be describing.  That's certainly not how a C compiler would ordinarily handle such a file.  I'm not aware of any conventional term for it.

Comment: @Joshua, is there any way to make a compiler result file only contains the data segment?

Comment: `const` file scope variables do not generally end up in the `.data` segment in embedded systems. I have no idea what some ".dat" file has to do with anything. Normal embedded systems do not have files. Is this some sort of industrial PC or what is the context?

Comment: The compiler will generate an object file containing the defined data object.  The linker will locate that file in memory.  If instead you want a data file to be read at runtime from a filesystem, then you would simply write code to run on the host rather than the embedded system, that code would write the file then you copy/transfer that file to your embedded filesystem.  There is no compiler/linker  mechanism by which that code would magically be written to a raw data file.  What you think you have "seen" is not what you think.

Comment: It is just a "data object".  The fact that it appears in a separate translation unit than any other code is irrelevant. The linker will generate an external linkage symbol by which it can be referenced in any translation unit with an `extern const unsigned char configData[] ;` declaration.  More specifically it is a _global_ data object.  Being `const` qualified makes that perhaps OK, but in general https://www.embedded.com/a-pox-on-globals/.  Note also that an emb dd dvsystem may not even have a filesystem; you seem to be conflating a number of separate things.

Answer (score 1):

Interpreting as: "How can I embed a binary file into my C program at build time?"

This is how I do it. I use a custom build step to convert the binary file to a .c file.

In Makefile:

```
program: main.c configData.c resource.h # and more
    $(CC) -o program main.c configData.c # and more

configData.c: configData.dat bin2c
    ./bin2c configData.dat configData.c

bin2c: bin2c.c
    $(HOSTCC) -o bin2c bin2c.c
```

In resource.h:

```
extern char configData[];
extern size_t configDataLen;
```

In bin2c.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: bin2c binary.dat binary.c symbol\n");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *in = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (!in) { perror(argv[1]); return 1; }
    FILE *out = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if (!out) { perror(argv[2]); return 1; }
    int c;
    long len = 0;
    fprintf(out, "#include <stddef.h>\n");
    fprintf(out, "char %s[] = {"
    while ((c = getc(in)) > EOF) {
        if (len > 0) puts(',', out);
        fprintf("%d", c);
        ++len;
        if (ferror(out)) { perror(argv[2]); return 1; }
    }
    fprintf(out, "};\n");
    fprintf(out, "size_t %sLen = %ld;", len);
    if (ferror(out)) { perror(argv[2]); return 1; }
    if (fclose(out)) { perror(argv[2]); return 1; } /* Yup check fclose for errors */
    if (ferror(in)) { perror(argv[1]); return 1; }
    return 0;
}
```

In .gitignore:

```
bin2c
configData.c
```

People have done better than this. I've seen fancy linker scripts that enable the linker to take dat files. My method has the advantage of being easy to understand and portable.